# Why is "x in (y, z...)" faster than finding x in an existing tuple?

Tags: python, performance

I was trying different approaches of membership methods, and I found out something strange:

```
    %timeit 10 in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 230 ns per loop
```

while:

```
    t = (0, 1)
    %timeit 10 in t
The slowest run took 4.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 246 ns per loop
```

The same behaviour (with slightly different timings) happens in both Python 2.7.12 and 3.4.5.

Obviously, as the list grows, it takes more time to create the tuple object than referring to an existing one, but this doesn't seem to change linearly: the difference is usually about 15ns (with the tuple object "winning" over the reference) up until the tuple has 80 items or less. After that, the change is *huge*:

```
    t = tuple(range(81))
    %timeit 10 in t
10000000 loops, best of 3: 70.9 ns per loop


    %timeit 1 in (0, .., 79)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 54.2 ns per loop

    %timeit 1 in (0, .., 79, 80)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 519 ns per loop
```

I thought that it depended only on the length of the tuple, but the `%timeit` of the tuple creation alone doesn't change between 80 or 81 items.

So, what's going on?

Comment: To have optimizations phase out as constants get over a given size isn't exactly uncommon -- note how small integers are interned, but large ones aren't. Something comparable for tuples as their length changes wouldn't be any surprise.

Comment: That said, when I wrap this statement in a function, both versions disassemble (using `dis.dis()`) to the same bytecode, and appear to have comparable performance -- meaning I can't replicate your result; certainly not with any difference of remotely the same magnitude.

Comment: I didn't think of that: it might  be a result of some optimization [not] used on my distribution, or even something related to the CPU. Unfortunally both my computers use similar configurations, but I'll dig into it as soon as possible. Let's see if anyone else is having similar results, in the meantime.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not testing evaluating the line, but calling a function already defined to have the code in question. If the optimization at hand is for the parse phase (which wouldn't be surprising), then testing by this mechanism would evade it.

Comment: ...but if that's the case, I'm hard-pressed to see why the difference you're asking about would matter for any real-world use case (since in the real world, code tends to be defined in functions). Note the "practical" specifier AND-ed into the on-topic definition at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic